# ListView in Android hides first element when SoftKeyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a problem in an activity where I show a listView and an EditText field (see picture below). I want to use the soft input method **adjustPan** and not **adjustResize**. When I add a new text in the field chat and the soft keyboard is not shown the items are shown correctly. The top most item is Item 1. When now the ListView is empty and I click in the EditText field the soft keyboard is shown. I enter now a new text and press then the button "Senden" without closing the keyboard. Then my Item 1 is above the visible region of the screen of the device. In picture I want that Item 1 cames down, so that it's shown correctly (green arrow).

Here' are my layout XML's:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/messageList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/grid_chat"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="true" >
</ListView>

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_chat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="1" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chatLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/message_border"
        android:inputType="text" 
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="48dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_send"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-76dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" />
</GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

where the RelativeLayout is embedded in a tab:

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp" >
 </FrameLayout>
```

I tried to overwrite the OnGlobalLayoutListener to adjust the top of the ListView without success.

Does anyone have met the the same problem?

[image: Red like it is: Green like it should be]

Comment: I think right way is to hide keyboard in send button click.

Comment: And waht is if you want send several messages without closing keyboard?

Comment: if you can not hide keyboard then how user will know which last message is his/her sended?